# CAGradientLayer in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has an `UIView` (`gradientView`) where I want to apply the gradient. This cell has AutoLayout, and so I want to update the gradient frame when the `gradientView` frame changes.

I have tried the following, but none of them worked:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
     self.gradient.frame = self.gradientView.bounds;
}

-(void)updateConstraints{
    [super updateConstraints];
    self.gradient.frame = self.gradientView.bounds;
}

-(void)updateConstraintsIfNeeded{
    [super updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    self.gradient.frame = self.gradientView.bounds;
}
```

also I can't use this inside the cell:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest create a new `UIView` subclass whose backing layer (`layerClass`) is a `CAGradientLayer`. Apply the colors as needed. Whenever the view's `bounds` change, iOS will internally resize the `layer` too.

If you want to make it even simpler, just grab `OBGradientView` from here and use it in your project. https://github.com/ole/OBGradientView

Comment: can you exemplify please?

Comment: https://github.com/ole/OBGradientView Just put this in your project, and use this UIView subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always use KVO for changing layers frame. Put this line after cell subviews has been loaded (`-(void)awakeFromNib` if you're using IB/storyboards). It's important that this line will be called only once in cells lifetime!

```
[self.gradientView.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

then just implement this method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if(object==self.gradientView.layer && self.gradient.superlayer!=nil){
        CGRect newFrame = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGRectValue];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.gradient.frame = newFrame;
        });
    }
}
```

I put frame update in dispatch_async block since without it layer was not updated.

And don't forget to remove observer eg. in dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [self.gradientView.layer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds"];
}
```

Comment: that worked, i just have one question. when the table view i design the first time the gradient fits with an animation. Any ideia why?

Comment: @rob180 nope, maybe `gradienView` or `gradient` frame is `CGRectZero` at the beginning and so iOS decides to animate this big change in size?

Comment: they are not zero, i have to find a way to disable this animation